# spring bootアプリケーションの起動について

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

spring bootで作成したアプリケーション（jar）を別のプロジェクトのクラスから起動したいです。
方法を調べましたがわかりません。
参考になるキーワード、サイトなどをご教示ください。
クラスローダーが作成できればいいのかなと思ってます。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/155800

Answer (score 1):

comandlinerunerクラスでできることがわかりました。